# C# Converting values passed as arguments to variables

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, constructor, arguments

I am having trouble understanding the relationship between variables and arguments passed to a method. The program below is supposed to take three integers from the main method (`M`, `D`, `Y`) and use various methods to validate if it is a valid date. This includes ensuring the year is between 1900 and 2100, as well as making sure the month is 1-12, and the day is within that month's range of days (including Feb 29th on leap years). If the date from the main method is not valid, the program should say so and print the default date of 1/1/1900. The code below always prints the default no matter what arguments are provided. I believe that this is because there is an issue with how I am using either the variables `M`, `D`, `Y` or the variables `Month`, `Day`, `Year`. This program is for an assignment in which I have to use all methods and constructors in the code below. I am unsure how to have the arguments `M`, `D`, `Y` get turned into the variables `Month`, `Day`, and `Year`, so they can be printed by the `ShowDate` method which was provided for me.

```
class Date
{
    private int Month;
    private int Day;
    private int Year;

    // Sets date to 1/1/1900
    public Date()
    {
        Month = 1;
        Day = 1;
        Year = 1900;
    }

    public Date(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        SetDate(M, D, Y);
    }

    public Boolean SetDate(int M, int D, int Y)
    {

        if (ValidateDate(M, D, Y))
        {
            Month = M;
            Day = D;
            Year = Y;
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalide date");
            SetDefaultDate();
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void SetDefaultDate()
    {
        Month = 1;
        Day = 1;
        Year = 1900;
    }
    // Determines if date is valid.
    public Boolean ValidateDate(int M, int D, int Y)
    {
        ValidateMonth();
        ValidateDay();
        ValidateYear();

        if (ValidateMonth() && ValidateDay() && ValidateYear())
        {
            ShowDate();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
        // Determines if month is valid.
    public Boolean ValidateMonth()
    {
        if (Month >= 1 && Month <= 12)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
        // Determines if year is valid.
    public Boolean ValidateYear()
    {
        if(Year >= 1900 && Year <= 2100)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
        // Determines if day is valid
    public Boolean ValidateDay()
    {
        IsLeapYear();

        if(Month == 1 || Month == 3 || Month == 5 || Month == 7 || Month == 8 || Month == 10 || Month == 12)
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 31)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 4 || Month == 6 || Month == 9 || Month == 11)
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 30)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear())
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 29)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 2 && !IsLeapYear())
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 28)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Determine if year is a leap year
    public Boolean IsLeapYear()
    {
        if ((Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0) || (Year % 400 == 0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

        // Print date to screen in format M/D/Y
    public void DisplayDate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ShowDate());
    }

    public String ShowDate()
    {
        StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0} / {1} / {2}", Month, Day, Year);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", myStringBuilder);
        return (myStringBuilder.ToString());

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Date NewDate = new Date();
        NewDate.SetDate(11,11,2011);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Have you used the debugger to step through your code. If I'm honest the path your program takes its not very 'nice'. Its very complicated and not easy to follow for what should be a simple path. You've got the idea in some places but I think you need to do a bit of studying on basic Object orientated principles

Comment: You need to set your fields from the values passed in so `Month = M;` not `M = Month;`.

Comment: I dont want to just post the editted code as that won't help you learn. In short almost all of the code that you use after SetDate, doens't take any arguments all you are doing is validating the default values you have set on your class level fields. All you're validation methods need to take arguments, (M,D and Y) and you need to validate the ones you are trying to set on to the Date object, not the ones you have already set as the default

Comment: you also have a lot unnecessary calls to methods everywhere

Comment: Also `ValidateDate` doesn't actually validate the values you pass in.  It validates your fields.  So either change that to validate the arguments you pass in (as in make `ValidateYear` actually take the year you pass in) or just set the initial values to your fields before calling the validation method.

Comment: Finally you might want to try using the `DateTime` class which can check if a date is valid without having to recreate all the logic involved.

Comment: @Dave thank you very much for the thoughtful reply. I will look into making sure that the program is actually validating the correct info. Also, I am not sure how to use the debugger in Visual Studio. It has not yet been covered in this class, but is there any online reasources you recommend?

Comment: @ZL4892 You're welcome. The Microsoft documentation is always a good place to start, it is, in my opinion, outstandingly good. Check it out for debugging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017 . The dubugger is one of the best tools for helping to understand your code, learn to use it and you'll be glad you did

Answer (score 1):

You never assign `M`, `D` or `Y` to your `Month`, `Day` and `Year` fields, so you are checking against your default values, which will all be zero by default. You *could* assign `M`, `D` and `Y` to their corresponding intended variables, but then you wouldn't be validating the input, just validating your fields. Instead you could have your methods accept parameters and check what you pass to it:

```
public Boolean ValidateMonth(int month)
{
    if (month >= 1 && month <= 12)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then when you call it

```
 ValidateMonth(M);
```

And then you can do the same thing for the other two methods.

Also in your `ValidateDate()` method you have three useless calls to `ValidateMonth()`, `ValidateDay()` and `ValidateYear()`. You call each of these methods twice. (Once in the beginning, and then again in the `if` statement.) You can remove these:

```
 public Boolean ValidateDate(int M, int D, int Y)
{
    //Remove these:
    //ValidateMonth();
    //ValidateDay();
    //ValidateYear();

    if (ValidateMonth() && ValidateDay() && ValidateYear())
    {
        ShowDate();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should initialize the class with the values given. Currently your default constructor initializes `M`, `D`, and `Y` but the constructor that takes arguments does not.

You can address this by changing the constructors to be more like this:

```
public Date() : this(1,1,1900)
{
}

public Date(int M, int D, int Y)
{
    Month = M;
    Day = D;
    Year = Y;
}
```

Once the class is initialized, it's just a question of exposing a property or method to validate the values that are already held in the class. You shouldn't need to pass the month, day, and year into a method again, since they're already set. So the validate method might look like this:

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return ValidateDay() && ValidateMonth() && ValidateYear();
    }
}
```

And in your main program:

```
Date newDate = new Date(11,11,2011);
if (newDate.IsValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date is valid.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date is not valid.");
}
```